# aplay on Kali Nethunter

Tags: linux, audio, python

Any idea how to get an audio file to play from the command line on Kali NetHunter?

I'm using aplay in a python script...which works fine on a Kali VM, but returns this error on Nethunter:

"aplay: main:788: audio open error: Invalid argument"

It doesn't have to be aplay either (that's just what I have been trying to make work)...really any way to play a 5 second .wav file from the command line or via some sort of python script on Nethunter will work. I's guessing it has something to do with aplay interfacing with the soundcard on the Nexus. I tried specifying the device (-D hw:0,0), but it still returns the same error.

Running this on a Nexus 5 btw...

Thanks!

***EDIT:

So first I tried `aplay -D front` and `aplay -D plughw:0,0` to no avail. They both returned the same error.

Next, I tried installing pulseaudio. I VNC'd into a local kali desktop on the phone just so I could install/open VLC player and change the output of the audio to pulse. I tried `aplay -D pulse` and also tried `paplay -D pulse`...but neither worked.

Here is the output when I ran it with paplay:

```
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

Here is when I ran it with `aplay -D pulse`:

```
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM pulse
aplay: main:788: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

Here is the output of `aplay -L`

```
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default:CARD=msm8974taikomtp
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=msm8974taikomtp
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=0
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=1
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=2
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=3
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=4
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=5
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=6
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=7
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=9
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=10
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=11
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=12
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=13
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=14
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=15
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=17
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=18
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=19
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=20
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=22
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=24
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=26
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=28
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=30
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=31
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=32
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=33
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=34
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=36
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=38
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=40
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=44
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=45
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=0
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=1
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=2
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=3
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=4
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=5
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=6
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=7
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=9
    msm8974-taiko-mtp-snd-card, 
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=msm8974taikomtp,DEV=10
```

Thanks for the help with this guys. I literally just need to get it to play from the command line. I can change the script to make it use whatever program/utility works. It doesn't have to be aplay/pulse (just wanted to reiterate that).

Thanks again!

EDIT:

Here is the requested output:
`Linux version 3.4.0-gb7558f2 (root@kali) (gcc version 4.7 (GCC) ) #2 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 7 02:16:12 UTC 2015` is the output of /proc/version.

I could definitely install an older version of ALSA. I just didn't realize that was the problem. Let me purge this new version and try an older one and see what I come up with.

Comment: Assuming you are running Pulseaudio, you'll have to use the compatibility layer (`aplay -D pulse`, or `aplay -D default` with a proper configuration that selectes `pulse` as `default`), or use `paplay` instead of `aplay` in the first place. The reason is that Pulseaudio opens all ALSA devices, so you can't use `hw:0.0`. If you are *not* running Pulseaudio, please edit question with output of `aplay -L`, and try again with `aplay -D front` or `aplay -D plughw:0,0`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Edited the post with some additional info.

Comment: Ok, deinstall Pulseaudio again (unless you need it), it only complicates things. A "sharded memfd" is a feature introduced in kernel 3.17. I suspect your kernel is quite a bit older than the applications/libraries you have installed, and that leads to problems. What does `cat /proc/version` say? Can you install a newer kernel, or older versions of ALSA?

Comment: `Linux version 3.4.0-gb7558f2 (root@kali) (gcc version 4.7 (GCC) ) #2 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 7 02:16:12 UTC 2015` is the output of /proc/version.

Comment: I could definitely install an older version of ALSA. I just didn't realize that was the problem. Let me purge this new version and try an older one and see what I come up with.